# Kafka Kraft - Reassign broker as broker,controller

Tags: apache-kafka, controller, kraft

We have had a small KRaft cluster running successfully for over a year.  Current cluster consists of 6 hosts:

- 3 broker,controller (nodes 1,2,3)
- 3 broker (nodes 4,5,6)

We want to transition nodes 4 & 5 to also be broker,controller.

After making changes to server.properties on all nodes in the cluster to reflect the new configuration.  We restarted kafka on all nodes expecting to see the new controllers added to the voters as configured by controller.quorum.voters, but only the original 3 appeared.

Do we need to do anything else to have these appear as voters?  Do we need to reformat the storage on these hosts?

Is there an easy way to list the controllers in the cluster? (we use the kafka-metadata-shell to list brokers, but haven't figured out how to list controllers)

Answer (score 0):

So it seems just removing the quorum-state file and restarting fixes this :-)